# When does out of memory happen?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Recently, when running our application, we met an out of memory exception.

This is the heap dump right before the exception happened

```
Heap
 def new generation   total 1572864K, used 366283K [0x00000006b0000000, 0x000000071aaa0000, 0x000000071aaa0000)
  eden space 1398144K, 13% used [0x00000006b0000000, 0x00000006bbb12d40, 0x0000000705560000)
  from space 174720K, 100% used [0x0000000710000000, 0x000000071aaa0000, 0x000000071aaa0000)
  to   space 174720K,   0% used [0x0000000705560000, 0x0000000705560000, 0x0000000710000000)

 tenured generation   total 3495296K, used 2658714K [0x000000071aaa0000, 0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000)
  the space 3495296K,  76% used [0x000000071aaa0000, 0x00000007bcf06ba8, 0x00000007bcf06c00, 0x00000007f0000000)

 compacting perm gen  total 42048K, used 41778K [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f2910000, 0x0000000800000000)
  the space 42048K,    99% used [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f28ccb80, 0x00000007f28ccc00, 0x00000007f2910000)

No shared spaces configured.
```

It looks like old gen was almost full (76%). I assume when it finally reaches 100% OOM happens. However, it looks like eden is only at 13%.

Can someone explain why OOM happens even if there is still some space in young gen?

Comment: Because there wasn't enough free memory to allocate the amount of space being requested. Percentages have nothing to do with it. @HNA If that was true in any meaningful sense the JVM wouldn't  start, but haven't you heard of virtual memory?

Comment: I'm pretty sure our application only allocate small variables one by one. so OOM in the need of large chunks of memory wouldn't happen.
virtual memory -- yes.
I'm actually curious why OOM happens when young gen is still 16%

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't perm gen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error  it's at 99% full / 270k free Edit: ah no, it seems permgen isn't reporting it's actual max there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611423/what-do-the-compacting-perm-gen-values-represent and 40M isn't that much compared to 1.5G heap.

Comment: you should paste the exception itself.

Answer (score 10):

There is a dozen of different reasons why JVM may throw `OutOfMemoryError`, including

- **Java heap space**: when trying to allocate an object or an array larger than maximum continuous free block in either of heap generations;
- **GC overhead limit exceeded**: when the proportion of time JVM spends doing garbage collection becomes too high (see `GCTimeLimit`, `GCHeapFreeLimit`);
- **PermGen space** (before Java 8) or **Metaspace** (since Java 8): when the amount of class metadata exceeds `MaxPermSize` or `MaxMetaspaceSize`;
- **Requested array size exceeds VM limit**: when trying to allocate an array with length larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2`;
- **Unable to create new native thread**: when reaching the OS limit of user processes (see `ulimit -u`) or when there is not enough virtual memory to reserve space for thread stack;
- **Direct buffer memory**: when the size of all direct ByteBuffers exceeds `MaxDirectMemorySize` or when there is no virtual memory available to satisfy direct buffer allocation;
- When JVM cannot allocate memory for its internal structures, either because run out of available virtual memory or because certain OS limit reached (e.g. maximum number of memory map areas);
- When JNI code failed to allocate some native resource;
- Etc. Not to mention that an application can throw `OutOfMemoryError` itself at any time just because a developer decides so.

To find out what is the reason of your particular error, you should at least look at the error message, the stacktrace and GC logs.