# JVM Out of Memory Causes

Tags: java, jvm

Questions are based on Oracle Hotspot JDK8.

When applicaton come across `java.lang.OutOfMemory: Java heap space` exception, I suppose, where are two possible reasons.

1. Allocated JVM heap size reaches `-Xmx` specified size and GC system cann't squeeze out enough space.
2. Allocated JVM heap doesn't reach `-Xmx`, but there are not enough physical memory for JVM heap to grow. Suppose `-Xms` < `-Xmx`.

I know `1` is a reason for JVM to throw out `java.lang.OutOfMemory: Java heap space` exception. **Is `2` a reasonable one cause?**

I find [some articles](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kD0w/what-is-the-difference-between-native-heap-memory-and-java-heap-memory?language=en_US) mentioned `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: native memory exhausted`, but they are all limited to IBM website. **Is this expetion limited to IBM implemented JVM or it is a standard expetion in JVM Specification?**

---

I did some experiments with code supplied by @Eugene in answer. As @Holger noted the result varies in different environments. I tested in on both CentOS x64 and Win7 x64, with Hotspot JDK8 x64.
**For simplicity swap and virtual memory are disabled.**

I increase memory bound (-Xmx and -Xms) step by step.

I. -Xmx < *available logic memory*

- On both CentOS and Windows it shows **OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

II. *available logic memory* < -Xmx < *max physical memory*

- CentOS: The GC try to Full GC serveral times, with *Allocation Failure*, and process be killed by system, leaving a message **Killed**.
- Windows: The GC try to Full GC serveral times, with *Allocation Failure*, and throw out  **OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

III. -Xmx > *max physical memory*

- CentOS: same as in II
- Windows: same as in II

IV. -Xms > *max physical memory*

- CentOS: JVM seems fail to start. Error message is like:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e62a0000, 349569024, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

- Windows: JVM failed to start. Error message is like:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

---

So, the same JVM behave differently in different OS.

- On windows, the OS doesn't kill JVM.  And JVM always throw out **OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** when memory usage grow exceeds.
- On Linux, the OS kill processes when there is not enough memory.
- On both OS JVM failed to start when available memory doesn't satisfy JVM minimal requirement.

Comment: Why don't you **try it** and see what happens? Set `-Xmx` to more than you have virtual space on your computer, then run a program that allocates space until it dies. --- *Hint:* Might be easier to run that in a Virtual Machine or in Docker, where you can better control how much memory the "machine" has.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33927030/3448419

Comment: It depends on the particular environment (including JVM implementation) whether a) `-Xmx` requires physical memory (rather then logical memory/swap space) and b) it allows to specify more maximum memory than the system can handle. There’s even that infamous Linux feature of overcommitting memory, i.e. it guarantees the availability of the memory in that the allocation request will never fail, but it just kills processes randomly when being out-of-memory.

Comment: @Holger from what I remember `-Xmx`, currently, will "commit" that much memory, that isn't resident yet. As to point number (2) : every single java person dealing with containers, especially kubernetes should be aware of this sudden death, especially since it does not support swap. Excellent comments.

Comment: @Andreas I tried it seems it is get killed by system when in situation 2

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are more reasons for a GC to fail with "out of memory" as the comment under your question explains.

Proving point number (2) is easy, just create some code that always allocates:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(1);
}

static void test(int x){
    List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(x == 1){
        byte [] b =new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        b[100] = 42;
        list.add(b);
    }

    System.out.println(list.hashCode());
}
```

And run this with `-Xms1g -Xmx100g`, on a system that has less then `100g` of RAM. You can enable GC logs (I did with `"-Xlog:heap*=debug" "-Xlog:gc*=debug"` in java-9 flags for example) and see how hard GC is trying to cope with this constant allocation, ultimately failing.

Comment: I tried it on CentOS with JDK8 (swap off). It is get killed by system when -Xmx is larger then pyhsical memory and JVM consumes all avaliable memory, only leaving a message **Killed**. So does it proves that I it show *OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space*, it could not be reason 2?

Comment: @SuN interesting. On my mac it dies with OOM. Did you run this in a container may be?

Comment: No, I run the test in VirtualBox with CentOS and Windows 7 as Guest OS. More Details a listed in question description *Section II Experinment*.

Comment: @SuN exactly. You run in a virtualized container via VirtualBox. What you see is pretty much expected.